# I have a list of values, some are in MB, some are in KB, some are in GB. I need to convert them to MB. IS there any formula for the same?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of values in excel cells. They are in different sizes: KB, MB, GB. I need to convert them into MB.

I have tried convert, but it is not working. The data that I am getting is coming from a system. I found that excel has number format defined for sizes. If I am trying to convert these cells to MB using number format, it is only changing the unit. The value remains same. For eg. a cell has value 2GB, if I change the format to MB, it will make it as 2 MB and not 2048 MB.
Now, i need to convert thousands of values to a single unit using formula. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Without providing sample data and showing expected output, I can only presume your data will look like the following and you just want to return the equivalent numerical value in **MB**:

[image: Sample]

I created a **Helper Lookup Table** which has two **named ranges**:

- **Unit**: being a list of units that need to be converted into MB;
- **C_Rate**: being the conversion rate for each corresponding unit against MB.

Suppose your data is in `A2:A10`, input the following formula in Cell `B2`and drag it down:

```
=--TRIM(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2))*IFERROR(INDEX(C_Rate,MATCH(RIGHT(A2,2),Unit,0)),1)
```

Please note I have formatted the result to show four decimal places.

The logic is to use **TRIM+LEFT** to find the original numerical value from the data, multiply it by the conversion rate which is being looked up using **INDEX+MATCH** from the `C_Rate` list by the corresponding `Unit` from the data.